# famous meteor full-width surface on initial page load 16px from edge

Tags: meteor, famo.us, surface

On initial page load: [DEMO HERE](http://famo-meteor-fullwidth-surface-prob.meteor.com/), the surface size falls 16px short of the full page width.

The modifier is set to `[undefined,undefined]` so it should take the parent's dimensions.

When you click to a different route ('bouncy' or 'flippy') and come back to it ('home'), the surface is now the full width of the page.  Also, if you open the dev tools/inpsector, this causes it to reflow to the full width.

I've tested this without meteor using the same css and it works without this issue.

I'm using Meteor 1.0 with the `raix:famono` package, the `mjn:famous` package, they both produce the same problem.  Occurs on Chrome 39/Safari 8.0.1/FF 34.0/IE 11 (33px short on IE)

Answer (score 0):

This is from the user agent stylesheet.  There is a

```css
body{
    margin:8px;
}
```

that is causing the 16px shortness.  If you include a normalize.css to override these or `meteor add mrt:normalize.css`, you won't have this problem.